# tangent plane to level set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, surfaces, plane-curves, tangent-line

I am confused betweeen tangent plane to the level set(is it the same as level surface?) and to the tangent plane on the surface?

I know the formula $z=f(x,y): z-z_0 = f_{x}(x_0)(x-x_0) +f_y(y_0)(y-y_0)$ but cannot understand for which case it corresponds. 
Also I found some example where it was just without $z$ and $z_0$ : $f_{x}(x_0)(x-x_0) +f_y(y_0)(y-y_0)=0$

What whould be the difference between two tangent planes? It would be very nice if someone could explain it on the numerical example.

Answer (score 1):

This one

$$z-z_0 = f_{x}(x_0)(x-x_0) +f_y(y_0)(y-y_0)$$

is the general expression for the tangent plane to $z=f(x,y)$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ while

$$f_{x}(x_0)(x-x_0) +f_y(y_0)(y-y_0)=0$$

is the intersection of the tangent plane with $x-y$ plane $(z=0)$ when $z_0=0$.

For example $z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 \implies f_x=2x \quad f_y=2y$ then at $(1,1,2)$ the tangent plane is

$$z-2=2(x-1)+2(y-1)$$

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/tangent-planes-to-level-surfaces
Why then here in example 1 we do not write $w-16=2(x−1)+4(y−2)+2\sqrt11(z−\sqrt11)$?

Comment: @Sally we must refer to surface, that is an expression of this kind $z=f(x,y)$ that is $z-f(x,y)=0$. In example 1 we have $x^2+y^2+z^2-16=0$ and we are apply the same method. You should clarify why yhe formula by gradient works.

Comment: @Sally The key point is that the equation of a plane is given by $ax+by+cz+d=0$ where $(a,b,c)$ is a normal vector to the plane.

Comment: @Sally Now if we have a surface $F(x,y,z)=0$ the normal vector at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by the gradient vector at that point that is $$F_x(x_0,y_0,z_0) \vec i + F_y(x_0,y_0,z_0) \vec j + F_z(x_0,y_0,z_0) \vec k$$.

Comment: @Sally Then we know $(a,b,c)=(F_x(x_0,y_0,z_0) , F_y(x_0,y_0,z_0) , F_z(x_0,y_0,z_0) )$.

Comment: Then for example 1, if we had to find tangent plane for $x^2+y^2+z^2=10 $ at the same point, what would the tangent plane be?
Should I add -6 for the given answer in example 1?

Comment: @Sally To find the plane we need that it passes through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ that is $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$.

Comment: @Sally You can't at the same point since that point doesn't belong to $x^2+y^2+z^2=10$. Read carefully what I wrote and try to understand how it works, otherwise you can't apply it avoiding mistakes.

Comment: I got it then. I was confused because in my example which I was solving, the point did not belong to the level surface. It seems it is a typo

Comment: @Sally The steps are: 1) We have the surface F(x,y,z)=0, 2) We select a point on it $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ such that $F(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0$, 3) Find the gradient at that point, 4) Set the condition for the plane to contain $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Comment: @Sally Well done! What it matters is that you are aware about the theory behind.

Answer (score 0):

Case $1)$    $$z= f(x,y)$$

Tangent plane is : $$z-z_0 = f_{x}(x_0)(x-x_0) +f_y(y_0)(y-y_0)$$

Case $2)$

$$ F(x,y,z)=0$$

The normal to the tangent plane is $$N=\nabla F =(\partial F/\partial x,\partial F/\partial y,\partial F/\partial z)$$ evaluated at $(x_0,y_0,z_0).$

The equation of Tangent plane is then,

$$ a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$$

where $N=(a,b,c)$ is the said normal vector.

Note that Case $2$ is  a generalization of case $1$

We can wright $z= f(x,y)$ as $$ F(x,y,z)= z- f(x,y)=0$$